# How to Turn xcdatamodel file into xcdatamodeld file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcdatamodel

I still have an xcdatamodel file.

However, when I created a new project, xcode generate an xcdatamodeld file (with a d).

I want to convert my xcdatamodel file into xcdatamodeld file. I know that xcdatamodeld is some form of directory.

How would I do that?

I can't copy the entity to the xcdatamodeld file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer from [How to create the magic .xcdatamodeld folder / package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518000/how-to-create-the-magic-xcdatamodeld-folder-package/4518137#4518137):

> To create a model bundle you select the single model, open the `Editor` menu in the main menu and select `Add Model Version…`.

Comment: Where is the design menu? There is no such thing?

Comment: @Jim see the answer again, @Stuart edited it so it is usable with Xcode4. I'm still using xcode3 and I wasn't aware of the fact that apple shifted around the menus.

Comment: time to change again... there's no Add Model Version option on the Editor menu in Xcode 4.2... I love Xcode 4.2 so much that I spank myself everyday.