# Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model after deleting app from device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

I'm receiving an `'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'` error after deleting my application from device. I'm testing an iPhone app in an iPad device. I've put this code to check if I have the file in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Name" withExtension:@"momd"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[modelURL path]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [modelURL path]); //This is printed because file exists
    }
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

The problem is that `[NSManagedObjectModel initWithContentsOfURL]` is returning nil value.
I've done the following things, with no success:

1. Change managedObjectModel instantiation with this `__managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];`
2. Cleaned Build Folder and Cleaned project
3. Restarted Xcode
4. Restarted computer
5. Changed "momd" to "mom"
6. `.xcdatamodeld` is in Copy Bundle Resources and Compile Sources
7. Renamed `.xcdatamodeld` and cleaned and closed Xcode project several times
8. Turned off and on the device
9. Deleted folders from: `$ cd /Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
10. Changed sqlite name for forcing database generation
11. Deleted (again) application from devine

I've been searching the solution for hours, and I still cannot find it.

Comment: Does it work on the simulator?  Are you able to open the `.xcdatamodeld` file in Xcode?

Comment: Alan, I'm able to open the `.xcdatamodeld` file in Xcode, but the application is not working in the simulator. It launches, but only displays a black screen.

Comment: I think I've found something... I've just realized that I had not deleted all the files living in `/Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`, so when I did this the simulator went OK, even the managedObjectModel. 

Is there any way to delete these files in the device?

Comment: Deleting the app from the device should remove the files.

Comment: Now the app launches in the simulator (only if I delete DerivedData and Reset Content and Settings) but I'm getting the same `managedObjectModel` error.

Comment: if the file exists at the url, then best guess is corrupted model.  can you revert to prior revision in version control?

Comment: So what you should do is create a new demo project (single view controller). Copy your model to that project, and add the above code. Run it a few times to be sure it fails like your main project. Zip it up and put on DropBox, then update your Question with a link to the project.

Comment: It seems that there is no `.mom` file inside the `.momd` directory. Also, there is no `.xcdatamodeld` and it seems that Xcode is not finding the `.xcdatamodel` that exists in the project. I'll try to solve the issue adding an `.xcdatamodeld`.

Comment: I've just posted the solution. The problems with the simulator were Xcode issues, I've just updated to 4.5 and everything regarding the iPhone Simulator works fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally, after two days trying to solve this issue, I've found the solution here:

[How to create the magic .xcdatamodeld folder / package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518000/how-to-create-the-magic-xcdatamodeld-folder-package/4518137#4518137)

I'm now finishing a project that other developer started, and it seems that he didn't pushed the latest changes to the repo, but those changes were in the app in the device, and when I removed the app I deleted the right `.xcdatamodeld` file. The problem was that I had just a `MyApp.xcdatamodel` file in the project, and this was the reason of having a `momd` empty folder, it seems.

In order to create the right hierarchy of data model, the solution was quite easy:

1. Select the `MyApp.xcdatamodel`
2. Go to Editor > Add Model Version...

And this embedded the `MyApp.xcdatamodel` file into `MyApp.xcdatamodeld`. Now the `momd` folder has the `mom` files and the app runs OK. The only problem now is that I have two `MyApp.xcdatamodel`, one with a green selected icon, but both with the same content so no problem.

Answer (score 2):

I backed to build my first iOS app again. Today, I got this error:'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'.
Actually, that is easy to fix.
Please make this line of code:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"[name]" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

The [name] you filled in is same as your model file (.xcdatamodeld).
For example I got a TipRecord.xcdatamodeld then this line should be:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TipRecord" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"select xcdatamodeld" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

select exact url for resource name..

Answer (score 0):

it's relatively simple.

if you have an xcdatamodel file **without** versions: use the extension "mom" in your managedObjectModel declaration.
If your xcdatamodel has versions, you should use "momd".